# Mdbootstrap integration with asp.netcore mvc application

Tags: asp.net-core, multi-select, mdbootstrap

I have purchased mdbootstrap pro for multiselect control and want to use it in my asp.net core mvc application. How can I integrate this?

[image]

Comment: You can find the corresponding tutorial on their official website: [installation guide](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/angular/getting-started/net-core-integration/), [Admin Dashboard + .NET Core + ASP.NET Core](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/integrations/admin-dashboard-net-aspnet/). Here is an [example](https://github.com/Matixk/mdb-.NET-core-starter) you can refer to.

Comment: doesn't help much

Comment: Can you download its js file and css file?

Comment: I have done but having trouble - details are in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73656564/manually-installing-mdb5-pro-multiselect